# Chaining URL Rewrite rules in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2.4

Need some help writing a re-write rule in apache v2.4.

I have a web app which is hosted in tomcat v8.0.29 which has this url:

http://myapptest:8080/app

Through the magic of mod_jk and the apache rewrite engine, I've been able to clean that up to just http://myapptest.

I now have SSL configured in apache and I need http://myapptest and https://myapptest to get redirected to https://myapptest.domain.com.

In httpd-ssl.conf, I have this vhost configuration which handles the rewrite stuff:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName myapptest
  RewriteEngine on    
  RewriteRule   ^/$ /app [NC,PT,L]    
  DocumentRoot "c:/apache/tomcat/webapps/app"
  JkMount /* myapp          
  ErrorLog "logs/myapptest-error.log"
  CustomLog "logs/myapptest-access.log" common
  ...other stuff...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then, in httpd-vhosts.conf I'm handling the redirection for the http traffic on port 80.

```
<VirtualHost myapptest:80> 
    ServerName myapptest
    Redirect      /   https://myapptest.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The last piece I'm missing is how to handle the redirect for https://myapptest?

If there is a better, cleaner way to handle this I am very open to that as I'm not an expert on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid a hostname inside the VirtualHost tag:

```
# First listed is the default for port 80
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName myapptest.domain.com
</VirtualHost>

# Capture the short hostname and redirect to FQDN
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName myapptest
    Redirect      /   https://myapptest.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, covener. I'm not seeing how https://myaptest will get redirected to the FQDN?

Comment: When the host header is "myapptest" it will be sent to the 2nd vhost. The 2nd vhost redirects everything to the FQDN with the Redirect directive.

Comment: Great! And if I use https://myapptest, that'll get redirected to https://myapptest.domain.com also?

Comment: "HTTPS://" got stripped off of my comment

Comment: Just do the same thing for the 44e vhosts

Comment: Thanks, covener. Do the 443 vhosts go in httpd-ssl.conf file or can they be defined in httpd-vhosts.conf file?